# How to provide access to an Active Directory group to a folder in a document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have a need where we need to provide contribute access to an AD group to a folder in a document library without adding the AD to document library level. If we add AD group to document library level then we need to break security for each folder, because we only need the AD group to have one folder at 3rd level in hierarchy.

Is it possible to provide access to AD group/user directly to a folder?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't it possible to break security on the folder level?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can easily apply permission to a folder of a document library. Even you can apply permission to the document library.

At first, create your document library and add a folder under this document library. Then click the check box of the left side of the folder/item. You can now see a "Document Permission" button on the top ribbon. Click the "Document Permission" button. You have to stop inheriting permission. You can do so by clicking "Stop Inheriting Permission" button from the top ribbon. 
Now, you have to remove all permissions. Then, Click "Grant Permission" button and add permission.

I think it would help you. 
Thanks